# MySQL complains key exists but I can't find it

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, constraint

I have a large (in both schema and data) MySQL database with lots of foreign key constrains. Recently I have discovered that some script can not create a table because key with given name already exists.

I traced down the problem to the following:

If I run something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `bar` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `BAZ` FOREIGN KEY (`bar`) REFERENCES `qux` (`bar`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I'm getting:

> ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table 'foo'

But if I:

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = "my_db"
   AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE "BAZ";
```

I'm getting an empty set.

I have also tried to dump the schema and search for "BAZ" there but found nothing.

Creating a table naming foreign key anything but "BAZ" goes through.

How could it be?

Comment: Anything from `SHOW CREATE TABLE BAZ;` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;`?

Comment: Both negative: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '...' doesn't exist`.

Comment: Does it work if you define the table with `CREATE TABLE foo (
  bar int UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES qux (bar) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);`  ?

Comment: @joanolo Yes, it creates a table successfully.

Comment: "If I run ***something*** like this:..." Please show us the exact statements you run.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE "BAZ";` show anything? What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ got plenty of results but in different schemas.

Comment: My point was, does the `CREATE TABLE foo` run in this database (`"my_db"`)? The error says that you already have `"BAZ"` as a foreign key in the database that the statement run. Can you try with `CREATE TABLE my_db.foo ...`?

Comment: Unfortunately the same error. :(

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but the issue is now gone. Maybe someone else repaired or optimised some other database on the server (yes, a remote one) but now I can create table without any issue. I'm very sorry for this confusion. Still hard to say what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have an index for a foreign key on some other table in your DB, which has the same constraint name and is thus causing a namespace collision.

If you are using all InnoDB tables (as you should in 2017), try this to locate the offending table:

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_indexes i
  JOIN information_schema.innodb_sys_tables t
 USING (table_id)
  WHERE i.name = 'BAZ';
```

Or this may work, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_foreign
WHERE id REGEXP 'BAZ$';
```

Comment: For me it was an orphaned temporary table which I couldn't even drop. This helped: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/get-rid-of-orphaned-innodb-temporary-tables-the-right-way/

Comment: I am unable to drop foreign keys using `ALTER TABLE` syntax, it gives error "Table doesn't exist in the engine". That is with few tables only. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Would you run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table \G` and post?  (scrub out any confidential table/column names if you have to)

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you're configured for case-insensitivity?

Does the following return any records:

```
SELECT   CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
         CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM     information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
where    lower(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) like "my_db"
and      lower(CONSTRAINT_NAME) like "baz";
```

Some references:

[mysql error code 1022 duplicate key in table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986152)

[Case insensitive constraint names in MySQL](https://richardfearn.wordpress.com/2007/03/12/case-insensitive-constraint-names-in-mysql/)